# In java I need help formatting with ("%.2f", int); it keeps outputting ##.##.#

Tags: java, number-formatting

I'm trying to print a double with only two decimals but the following code displays it as ##.##.#

```
 double x, i = 3, j = 3, y;


        x = Math.pow(i, j);
        System.out.printf("two decimal places is: %.2f", x);
```

Comment: Are you sure you're running that code?

Comment: that's my output: two decimal places is: 27.00

Comment: yes, It's the only thing I have going at the moment.

Comment: Can you post your exact output from your IDE or wherever you're running this code?

Comment: how about specifying locale : `System.out.printf(Locale.US, "two decimal places is: %.2f", x);`

Answer (score 0):

You should try [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html).Use the `0.00` pattern that specifies leading and trailing zeros, because the 0 character is used instead of the pound sign (#).

```
x = Math.pow(i, j);
//System.out.format("two decimal places is: %.2f", x);

DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
System.out.println("two decimal places is: " + decimalFormat.format(x));
```

But as mentioned in comments section, try to post us the exact console output, it can help us figure out why your code it's not working.